# Pyramid form from jsonsschema

Tags: python, json, forms, pyramid, jsonschema

I have a running python application that requires a JSON file. I want to create a web app and saw that pyramid (I am new to it) allows to create forms and save values into JSON.

But is it possible to generate the form from a jsonschema file?

Comment: Pyramid does not provide any form library. There are [Pyramid add-ons](https://trypyramid.com/resources-extending-pyramid.html) that provide form features, but I don't know whether any do exactly what you want. There might be a Python library out there which would work with Pyramid, but you'll need to do your own research.

Comment: Perhaps this is not of pyramid task and you can use https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form

Comment: @uralbash Indeed I saw this but from what I understand, I have to use REACT for that (which I do not want to).